# android mastercard paypass integration

Tags: android

I need to develop an android application which facilitate the credit card payment through mobile application i am not getting any start point to start with and their is no any documentation to 
find out the closer solution to this.
could anyone tell me how to integrate the mastercard paypass java sdk in android application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not possible right now !as it's api is available for java but it is not supported in android please refer to this link 
https://developer.mastercard.com/portal/display/forums/How+do+i+integrate+paypass+online+with+android+application

Answer (score 0):

You should try there Remote Secure Element API, this will let you to do NFC payment without having the SIM personalized with the card info.